# Only First and last fragment changes while clicking on bottom navigation

Tags: android

This is how I'm implementing bottom navigation

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/main_botton_navigation"
            android:background="@color/btn_bg"
            app:menu="@menu/main_bottom_nav_menu"
            app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
            app:itemTextColor="@drawable/text_selector"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/fragment"
            android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/main_appbar"
            android:layout_height="617dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/main_botton_navigation"
            app:defaultNavHost="true"
            app:navGraph="@navigation/main_bottom_nav"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="1dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="57dp" />
```

and this is how I'm doing in activity

```
val navController = findNavController(R.id.fragment)
        val appBarConfiguration =
            AppBarConfiguration(setOf(R.id.allFiles, R.id.recentFiles, R.id.bookMark, R.id.tools))
        setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
        binding.mainBottonNavigation.setupWithNavController(navController)
```

but only last activity is changed while clicking on last item other's are not changing

Answer (score 0):

Change your code like this and change fragment name according to yours.

```
// Setting Up ActionBar with Navigation Controller
    // Pass the IDs of top-level destinations in AppBarConfiguration
    var appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(
        topLevelDestinationIds = setOf (
            R.id.homeFragment,
            R.id.searchFragment,
            R.id.notificationsFragment,
            R.id.profileFragment
        )
    )
    setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
```

For a detailed understanding of Navigation library please read this article

https://medium.com/android-news/beginners-guide-to-bottom-navigation-with-android-jetpack-5485d2b8bbb5